# Troubleshoot parallax scroll function that overlaps on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap website with a parallax scroll effect. i love how it looks, except on a tiny screen it fails alignment. the "text over" sections don't elongate with it's content. in other words, the bootstrap feature stacks, while the parallax sections do not extend vertically to accommodate the stacked content. How can i fix this? :(
The site is live, so you can check it out... 
http://www.adeninedesign.net/

Comment: I'm not sure where to start. I suspect it's not possible to do what i want to do, but wanted to throw it out there to see if anyone had a hint before i scrap it.

Comment: Well if your issue is with alignment problems when the screen gets small I suggest looking into `media queries`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem by using a table to align some of the content to keep it from stacking quite as much. 
I had been using sub rows (child elements)... 
I'm not even sure if that is allowed.

like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 text-left">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
```

instead, this is my solution:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 text-left">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
```

However, I'm pretty sure that I could have solved this with the column system itself by assigning xs column alignments? maybe? i tried it briefly, it didn't give me the result i was looking for, i canned the attempt and went with the table - which i feel is the cheater solution here...